# C++ do while loop not continue

Tags: c++

After doing a certain task, it is supposed to ask `do you want to continue(Y/N)`, but instead it exits. It was working yesterday, but now it's not functioning.

Here's my code. It's in the lower part:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char yesNo;
    string bookName[50];
    string bookAuthor[50];
    string bookID[50];
    int i=0, choice; //for case 1
    string id; // for case 2
    
    do{
    
    cout << "==========================" << endl;
    cout << "LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM" << endl;
    cout << "==========================" << endl;
    cout << "[1] Add Books" << endl;
    cout << "[2] Delete Books" << endl;
    cout << "[3] Search Books" << endl;
    cout << "[4] View Book List" << endl;
    cout << "[5] Close Application" << endl;
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
    case 1: // add book
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter book name: ";
        getline(cin, bookName[i]);
        cout<<"Enter book author: ";
        getline(cin, bookAuthor[i]);
        cout<<"Enter book ID: ";
        getline(cin, bookID[i]);
        i++;
        cout<<"Book succesfully added!"<<endl;
        break;
    case 2: //delete a book
        int j;
        
        if(i!=0){
        cout<<"Enter the book ID you want to delete: ";
        cin>>id;
        for(int y=0; y<i;y++){
            if(id==bookID[y]){
                for(j=y; j<i; j++)
                bookID[j]=bookID[j+1];
                bookName[j]=bookName[j+1];
                bookAuthor[j]=bookAuthor[j+1];
                i--;
                break;
            }}
        }else{
                cout<<"Your library is empty"<<endl;
            }
        break;
    case 3: // search book
        if(i!=0){
        cout<<"Enter the book ID you want to search: ";
        cin>>id;
        for(int y=0; y<i;y++){
            if(id==bookID[y]){
                cout<<"Book name: "<<bookName[y]<<endl;
                cout<<"Book author: "<<bookAuthor[y]<<endl;
                cout<<"Book ID: "<<bookID[y]<<endl;
                break;
            }}
        }else{
                cout<<"Your library is empty"<<endl;
            }
            break;
        
    case 4: // display all the books
        if(i!=0){
        cout<<"All Books"<<endl;
        for(int x=0; x<i; x++){
      
          cout<<"Book name:"<< bookName[x] << endl;
          cout<<"Book author: "<< bookAuthor[x] << endl;
          cout<<"Book ID: "<< bookID[x] << endl;
          cout<<endl;
      }  
        }else{
            cout<<"The library is empty"<<endl;
        }
        
    cout<<"Do you want to continue (Y/N)";
    cin>>yesNo;


    }}while (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y');
        cout<<"Thank You!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a [mre], strip out what is not needed to reproduce the problem. The problem does not involve doing tasks, so strip them out. Replace that part of the code with a comment like `// Do stuff`. Also drop the menu -- your description of the problem did not need to mention that, which suggests your code does not need it. You should probably be able to get your code down to the loop, the "continue?" prompt, reading the response, and whatever definitions those require.

Comment: Fix the indentations in your code, and you will see that your `Do you want to continue` prompt is in the wrong place.

Comment: where should it go?

Comment: You put it inside of `case 4`. It should be after the `switch` exits instead.

Comment: Note: Constructing a [mre] would have also shown you that the prompt is out of place, or at least leave you with a mystery of why the braces don't match up. Many tricks available for diagnosing one's own code.

Answer (score 1):

If you fix the indentations in your code, you will see that your `Do you want to continue` prompt is in the wrong place. You put it inside of `case 4`, so when the user chooses any menu choice other than `4`, `yesNo` remains *uninitialized* and the `while` is likely to break (the chance of `yesNo` randomly containing `'y'` or `'Y'` without user input is very unlikely).

The prompt should be *after* the `switch` instead, eg:

```
...
do {
    ...
    switch(choice){
        ...
        case 4: // display all the books
            ...
        
            // REMOVED FROM HERE
            //cout<<"Do you want to continue (Y/N)";
            //cin>>yesNo;

            break; // <-- ADD THIS
    }

    // MOVED HERE INSTEAD!!!
    cout<<"Do you want to continue (Y/N)";
    cin>>yesNo;
}
while (yesNo == 'y' || yesNo == 'Y');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "do you want to continue" prompt is in the wrong scope. You need it to be in the loop body. In the above it is in the switch statement body.